# Creating TV Reminder with VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I'll appreciate if someone could give me a hand with this program.

Basically the program reminds the user 5 min and 30 min before the TV show starts, it has Tex-box input for Program Name, Channel, and air time. The input should go to the list-box and then when the times reaches it shows a messages box saying that the program starts in 5/30 min.

I'm having trouble to get index from the list (list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 0), when the program runs it just keep repeating the first item from (list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 0).

```
Public Class frm_main_window

Dim time_format As New DateTime

Private Sub tmr_current_time_label_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr_current_time_label.Tick

    lbl_current_time.Text = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss tt")

    lbl_5min_time.Text = Format(Now.AddMinutes(5), "hh:mm:ss tt")
    lbl_30min_time.Text = Format(Now.AddMinutes(30), "hh:mm:ss tt")

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    If list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 0 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(0) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 1 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(1) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 2 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(2) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 3 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(4) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 4 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(4) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 5 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(5) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 6 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(6) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 7 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(7) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 8 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(8) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 9 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(9) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    End If

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    If list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(0) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(1) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 2 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(2) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 3 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(3) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 4 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(4) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 5 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(5) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 6 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(6) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 7 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(7) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 8 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(8) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Contains(lbl_30min_time.Text) And list_box_tv_shows.TabIndex = 9 Then
        tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
        MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(9) & " " & "is starting in 30 minutes")
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub frm_main_window_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    lbl_current_time.Text = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss tt")

    lbl_program_time_goes_into_list.Hide()
    list_box_program_time_hide.Hide()
    list_box_program_name.Hide()
    lbl_30min_time.Show()
    lbl_5min_time.show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_click_save.Click

    list_box_tv_shows.Items.Clear()

    lbl_program_time_goes_into_list.Text = cbo_hours.Text & ":" & cbo_min.Text & ":" & cbo_sec.Text & " " & cbo_am_or_pm.Text

    list_box_program_time_hide.Items.Add(lbl_program_time_goes_into_list.Text)
    list_box_program_name.Items.Add(txt_box_program_name.Text)
    list_box_tv_shows.Items.Add(txt_box_program_name.Text & " | " & txt_box_tv_channel.Text & " | " & lbl_program_time_goes_into_list.Text)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why the vb6 tag?  VB.NET and VB6 are **not** the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the TabIndex property is.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your timer event.  Add another one for the 30 minute version (or create a re-usable sub, since the only thing that changes is what you are looking for and the display).  I would probably use a dataGridView so you don't have multiple listboxes

```
    For Each i As String In list_box_program_time_hide.Items
        If i.Contains(lbl_5min_time.Text) Then
            tmr_current_time_label.Stop()
            MsgBox(list_box_program_name.Items(i.indexof) & " " & "is starting in 5 minutes")
            If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                tmr_current_time_label.Start()
            End If
            tmr_current_time_label.Start()
        End If
    Next
```